# What are the parameters event and full_event of UILayout are for?

Tags: python, scripting, properties

can someone help me to understand the function of the parameters event and full_event of UILayout, please? The only description i can find ist this from the documentation (https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_77_release/bpy.types.UILayout.html#bpy.types.UILayout.prop):

```
event (boolean, (optional)) – Use button to input key events
full_event (boolean, (optional)) – Use button to input full events including modifiers
```

But what buttons can/should be used to input key events? I can't find an difference to the version without event=True. And i can't find an example, too.

Thanks

Comment: just guessing, but 'modifiers' in this case could be keys like `Ctrl`, `Shift`, `Space`

Comment: I think that could be right - this is my assumption, too. But that's not my main question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*'event'* and *'full_event'* parameters allow to get a keystroke value.

- *'event'*: a key with no modifier
- *'full_event'*: a key with modifiers

[image]

Here is a sample code:

```
import bpy

class HelloWorldPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Hello World Panel"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_hello"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "object"

    keymaps = []
    keymapitem = None

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        obj = context.object

        #Allow to get a key on a locally defined property
        layout.row().prop( obj, "myProperty", event = True )
        #Allow to get a key: no, does not work
        layout.row().prop( obj, "myProperty", full_event=True )

        #Allow to get a key on an existing property
        layout.row().prop( context.scene.game_settings, "exit_key", event=True )

        #Allow to get a full event key on a keymap item
        layout.row().prop( HelloWorldPanel.keymapitem, "type", full_event=True )

def register():
    #Enum property to define the allowed keys for this property
    bpy.types.Object.myProperty = bpy.props.EnumProperty( items=[('A','A',''),('LEFT_CTRL','LEFT_CTRL',''),('LEFT_ALT','LEFT_ALT','')] )
    bpy.utils.register_class(HelloWorldPanel)

    #Create a keymap and a key
    wm = bpy.context.window_manager
    km = wm.keyconfigs.addon.keymaps.new(name='Test', space_type='EMPTY')
    kmi = km.keymap_items.new(HelloWorldPanel.bl_idname, 'LEFT_SHIFT', 'PRESS')
    #Store them here
    HelloWorldPanel.keymaps.append(km)
    HelloWorldPanel.keymapitem = kmi

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(HelloWorldPanel)
    del bpy.types.Object.myProperty
    wm = bpy.context.window_manager
    for km in HelloWorldPanel.keymaps:
        wm.keyconfigs.addon.keymaps.remove(km)
    del HelloWorldPanel.keymaps[:]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Some explanations and remarks:

- For a locally defined property (myProperty in the code above): the property is an enum which defines the scope of the possible values. But it seems that the user will not be warned if she/he choose a not wanted value.
- You can use it for built in properties, like 'context.scene.game_settings' above.

But in both previous cases, I've found no solution to use *'full_event'*.

- Last example using a keymap item. Here choosing its type as attribute allows the usage of *'full_event'*.

I don't know why some are working with *'full_event'* and not others, as the enum described in the documentation seems to be the same. See the documentation [here](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.78b/bpy.types.KeyMapItem.html?highlight=keymap_item#bpy.types.KeyMapItem.type).

Comment: i've tried out your example. But unfortunately your answer is/was too late for me because i've already finished my master thesis. So I'll not search for further information. Nevertheless thanks for your answer.