# How to get the state of the modifier keys from the keyboard when changing a custom property?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I asked a similar - but slightly different - question already some time ago and I found a solution for a custom operator:
[How to detect if a modifier key is pressed when the value of a custom property is changed?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/181454/how-to-detect-if-a-modifier-key-is-pressed-when-the-value-of-a-custom-property-i)

But now I would like to get the state of the keys of the keyboard while manipulating a custom property. In other words can I create an Event in a set or update function of a property?

```
def _get_stampInfoUsed(self):
    val = self.get("stampInfoUsed", True)
    # get Event here in some way...
    if event.ctrl:
        print("Ctrl Pressed")

def _set_stampInfoUsed(self, value):
    self["stampInfoUsed"] = value
        
myProp: BoolProperty(
get = _get_stampInfoUsed,
set = _set_stampInfoUsed,
)
```

Thank you

Comment: Btw I would also like to add that I am very likely in a non-modal context.

Comment: I found some more clues in the documentation on the "prop" type: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.UILayout.html#bpy.types.UILayout.prop
(look at the arguments event and full-event)
And this thread provides some lights too but not all the parts of this puzzle: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71537/what-are-the-parameters-event-and-full-event-of-uilayout-are-for/184175#184175